# Sony Vaio C & D drives. How do I...?

Tags: hard-drive

all my info etc is stored on the 'C' drive, but next to nothing on the 'D' drive. How do I either switch drives (so new info etc goes on D) or transfer the info from C to d, so clearing out C drive?

I'm not that PC savvy, and am hoping that it's a simple operation.

I appreciate any help you can offer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [change the location of the *My Documents* folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310147) in Windows to *D* and move all of your personal files there.

In Windows 7 (and possibly Vista) you can add folder to your [Libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/libraries) and change their default save locations to folders on the D drive.

Just be sure to check not just the *percentage used* of the drives, but also their *total capacity* before doing this. There's little use to move stuff over if the D drive is too small.

Answer (score 0):

To move all info you can either:

- Copy and paste all content from one drive to the other
- Use Imaging software to image the partition and then restore the image onto the next partition

To have all new data to be stored on drive D you can:

- Go to C:\Users\"USERNAME" and then for each folder, right click > properties > Location and then change the location to D:\

What I normally do is partition my HDD to have an OS Partition and a Data partition, it also helps when reinstalling windows, you don't need to worry about backups.